# Get the number index through boolean opearator in python-pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, conditional-statements

Now I can get the expected value with boolean operator:

```
mask1 = df.val > 10
mask2 = df.val < 5
c1 = df[mask1]
c2 = df[mask2]
```

And I wish to get the slice between each point in `c1` and `c2`, that is, given a data frame `df` as below:

```
       val
0       9
1      12
2       5
3       2
4       11
5       9
6       9
7       3
```

The slices of `df[1:3]` and `df[4:7]` are what I want. First of all, I need to get the index `1`, `3`, `4`, `7` through `mask1` and `mask2`. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
c1 = df[mask1].index
c2 = df[mask2].index

print (c1)
Int64Index([1, 4], dtype='int64')
print (c2)
Int64Index([3, 7], dtype='int64')

print (df[c1[0]:c2[0]])
   val
1   12
2    5

print (df[c1[1]:c2[1]])
   val
4   11
5    9
6    9
```

It is same as:

```
print (df[1:3])
   val
1   12
2    5

print (df[4:7])
   val
4   11
5    9
6    9
```

If you need slice by `c1` or `c2` use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
print (df.ix[c1])
   val
1   12
4   11

print (df.ix[c2])
   val
3    2
7    3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wonder can I do something like `df[c1]` directly to get the value `12, 11` ?

Comment: You need add `ix` or `loc`, `print (df.ix[c1])` return `val
1   12
4   11` Btw, `ix` is faster.

Comment: But what about the column? `df.ix[c1, 'val']` ?

Comment: Yes, it works with column nice too `df.ix[c1, 'val']` and then get `Serie`, not `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

This suppose to work for you:

```
c1 = df[df['val'] > 10].index.tolist()
c2 = df[df['val'] < 5].index.tolist()
```

> output: c1 = [1,4]  c2 = [3,7]

Answer (score 0):

Subset the bigger data-frame to smaller one by that mask condition

```
df_mask1 = df[df.val > 10]
#in df_mask1  you will have index 1 and 4 [Rows of main dataframe]
#similarly
df_mask2  = df[df.val < 5] 
# you will have index 3 and 7 in df_mask2
```

or if you want to change some other column value by that mask condition you can use df.loc (just try serching on web).